# How can i add a view (dynamically) in android as shown in the picture below posted?

Tags: java, android

[this is the image by default.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hmfbt.jpg)

Now, what i want to do is add a exact same view when last (from left to right) view is clicked only when all three views are contained with images and names.
like below image shows it clearly.

[This image shows what i want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zjFO.jpg)

Comment: show the way you are draw the layout for default image. I have some solution: you can add three images, firstly you can hide them, when the last view is clicked, show them. Or we can add it from Java/ Kotlin

Comment: i have written xml file for them